# QGIS and Android Tablet

Tags: qgis, android, qgis-android

I can't download QGIS 2.8.2 via googlePlay. Device is not compatible. Device is Nexus 7 2012 with android 5.1.1
Do you have same issue? On old android 4.4 it was working fine.

Comment: requires Android 2.3 - 4.4 https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.qgis.qgis so it will not work with 5.1.1 until updated to do so.